# VBA want to use ">21" as a value not as a logical operator

Tags: vba, excel

In my requirement I have a column in which a cell value is defined as ">21", `14-21` so on and I need to filter based on criteria `>21` as a value not as a logical operator greater than 21.

Im declaring

```
Const gt=">21"

sub main()
.
.
.
.
sample gt

end sub

sub sample(grt as string)
.
.
.
.
.
.
Selection.autofilter field:=4 criteria1=grt

End sub
```

Can any body help me on this please!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: You have provided some code, but didn't say what doesn't work or what did you expect. Also, can you please specify the task in more details?

Comment: Not sure if this is a typo on your part or if it is actually in your code this way, but `criteria1=grt` should be `criteria1:=grt`. You also need to separate `field` and `criteria` with a comma, so that line should read `Selection.autofilter field:=4, criteria1:=grt`

Comment: thanks tim for your quick response, its typo error. What im trying to do is in my current sheet sheet1 which contains so many columns and filtering out  from a column (S) with the value i.e., ">21" note this is not a logical operator just ">21" value. After that it has to be copied and moved to another sheet.

A        lB       C      D      E
asd   dsdd   ddas  sssd  >21
dadf  bbdw  gege  gge   >21

Answer (score 1):

More than halfway into the reply, I realized it had already been covered by Tim's comment. If I reap any imaginary points for this, I'll split them!

This is what your code should have looked like:

```
Public Const gt As String = "=>21"

Sub main()
    sample (gt)
End Sub

Sub sample(grt As String)
    Selection.AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=grt
End Sub
```

If you are getting a type mismatch error, please indicate what line of code it is triggering on. Additionally, advise what datatype is used in the column you are autofiltering.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I wanna read ">21" as a value in my autofilter criteria not as a logical operator greater than 21. When Im trying to filter out its considering as logical operator greater than 21 instead of ">21" value. Please help on this Thanks- Vivek

Comment: That is a good question... I don't know if it is possible? If it is, it is beyond my knowledge. I've tried several things, but none work. I can make a workaround if you are willing to either change your dataset or create a helper column.

Comment: I dont want to change the cell values and I want to read it as value ">21". Please help me on this.

Comment: @vivek See updated code, I found out how to do it. :)